# Image processing java

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, javacv

I'm a complete beginner in java. In my final year project, I have to do something relate to real time image processing. What I am doing now is trying to convert the Matlab program to Java with the help of JavaCv. I won't really be able to deal with the 3-D martrix.
Here are 3 questions.

1. **Get the red component from an RGB 3-D image**: Matlab code: `Red=I(:,:,1);` Java code: `cvInRangeS(imgRGB, cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cvScalar(255, 0, 0, 0), imgR);` Can I do in this way in java?
2. **In a 1-D matrix, how to convert the follow code to java?** Matlab code: `imgB(find(imgA~=0))=255;` The Matlab code means, put a `int` 255 in `imgB` for every nonzero pixels from imgA.
3. **Can I extract some coordinate from 1-D `IplImage` type image?** If yes, how to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

> 1 - Get the R from RGB 3-D image Matlab code:Red=I(:,:,1); Java
>   code:cvInRangeS(imgRGB, cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cvScalar(255, 0, 0, 0),
>   imgR); Can i do in this way in java?

if you want to get the **Red** color from the image , You can try this:

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("////////image path"));
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
            int red = c.getRed();//////////here you get the Red color , you can make it array 2D 
            System.out.println(red);
        }
    }
```

> 2- In the 1-D matrix, how to convert the follow code to java? Matlab
>   code:imgB(find(imgA~=0))=255; The Matlab code means, put a int 255 in
>   imgB for every non zero pixels from imgA.

you can do this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < imgA.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgA.getHeight(); j++) {
            if (Color.BLACK.getRGB() != imgA.getRGB(i, j)) {
                imgB.setRGB(i, j, 255);
            }
        }
```

Note : Using [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to define the images